Show shipping/billing adress fields upon checkout
I have a Drupal 10 / Commerce installation. With this installation I have some user types (profiles) and a "private" user, should not enter address info upon registration.
But when that user is shopping, and going to Shipping / Billing page, the "Shipping" and "Billing" panes is not a form with all the address fields. But only a "Edit" button, which i can press and the fields appears.
Is there a way i can disable this feature, so the address fields will be visible all the time ?
I hope i makes any sense (And sorry for my english)
